# How to disable or closing CPU HOTPLUG in 4.2.2. kernel?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Using linux3.4 kernel-android 4.2.2 and 
compiled my own kernel and set default cpu governor is performance.

Eventhough performance governor, cpu0 kill cpu1 regulary, 
   Is there any way cancel hotplug and cpu0 and cpu1 online everytime.

Up cpu1 manuel  `(echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online)`
but then cpu0 kill cpu1 again.

Thanks...

```
>     <5>[ 1463.823251] **CPU1: shutdown**
>     <6>[ 1463.826297] [hotplug]: cpu(0) try to kill cpu(1)
>     <6>[ 1463.832847] [hotplug]: cpu1 is killed!
>     <7>[ 1464.122323] **cpu up:1**
>     <4>[ 1464.156379] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
>     <5>[ 1464.723240] **CPU1: shutdown**
>     <6>[ 1464.726262] [hotplug]: cpu(0) try to kill cpu(1)
>     <6>[ 1464.732851] **[hotplug]: cpu1 is killed!**
>     <6>[ 1473.123071] [BASE_I2C_DEBUG]receive temperature code: 0x04,0x41,0x01,0x24


>     root@android:/ # cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
>     cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
>     performance
>     root@android:/ #
```

Comment: Judging from timestamps in log you provided, CPU1 up/shutdown events happening back and forth. Any chance it's happening because of overhearing? If no, then it's the way hotplug is trying to save some power (disabling second CPU when it's not needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing the kernel code, I think it seems you can not disable hotplug cpu dynamically since there's no such interface in sysfs. You can unselect CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU when building the kernel if you don't need hotplug cpu.

`echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online` only make this cpu online, but it may be offline again judged by kernel.

And I think `scaling_governor` only affects the cpu frequency of which the mechanism is called `cpufreq` in kernel. It's a different mechanism from `hotplug cpu`. `performance` only set the cpu to the max frequency. But when there's no task running on this cpu, the `hotplug cpu` still can make it offline.

Comment: CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU only disables hotplugging due to CPU being idle. CPU hotplugging can also happen due to high CPU temperatures. For that you will have to disable your thermal governor in kernel.